# Get facebook total like count of a user

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-fql

I am using windows phone 8.1.

I am trying to get **total like count** of a user.

I have tried this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805968/get-facebook-posts-and-total-count-of-likes-for-each-post)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025566/parameter-for-like-count-with-facebook-api-v2-3)

```
133231234567890/?fields=likes.summary(true).limit(0)  
but it returns only id
```

```
133231234567890?fields=likes.summary(1)  
this returns all the likes not total like count.
```

```
133231234567890/likes?summary=1  
this also returns all the likes with their name , but not what i want.
```

I am testing it on Graph api explorer with my domo facebook id, and i have enabled the required permissions ,but i am unable to figure out what simple i am missing.

Comment: By total like count i mean the pages that user has liked.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, which is in status "assigned" at facebook:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1637494793192258/

Comment: So is there any other way to get total like count?

Comment: If this functionality is currently affected by a bug, I guess the answer is NO

Comment: i removed my answer, because i misinterpreted the question. it really does seem to be a bug.

Comment: I checked it several times  but this is at the bottom,"paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "Mjg2fdfdfefdjfdljYz",
      "after": "MzI2MdfdfdfdfdfZD"
    }, and before that i am shown all the likes.but there are no total-like-count